# Implicit conversion of std::shared_ptr to pointer type

Tags: c++, sdl

I have wrapper classes that will wrap a C Libary. In this case SDL. I'll shorten everything down to the neccessary details, if something is missing, please tell me in the comments.

So for example I have a class called `texture_t` which will wrap `SDL_Texture`

```
class texture_t
{
public:
...
private:
    SDL_Texture *tex;
}
```

Sometimes, it may be in a `shared_ptr`:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<texture_t> texture_ptr_t;
```

Now if I want to call a `SDL` function that takes a `SDL_Texture *` as an argument, I want my `texture_t` and `texture_ptr_t` to implicitly convert to it.

I tried implementing these operators in my class:

```
operator SDL_Texture *(void);
operator const SDL_Texture *(void) const;
```

But I still get `no viable conversion from texture_ptr_t to SDL_Texture *` errors. Can someone point me in the right direction for getting this right?

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you do this, you're hijacking a major C++ feature that is there to help you: type safety. Smart pointers themselves are not implicitly convertable for the same reason.

Comment: You're not under control of both parts of the conversion. `std::shared_ptr` has no way to convert to the raw ptr and and `SDL_Texture` Has no way to construct an object from such a ptr.

Comment: @NikosC. Meaningful user defined implicit conversions don't compromise type safety in general. I wish smart ptr were usable were ptr are.

Comment: You can dereference a shared_ptr like a raw pointer, is that not sufficient? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @curiousguy You can search for why smart pointers do not provide an implicit conversion to the pointer type they're managing to find why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @NikosC. It's a bad idea if the programmer doesn't know what he is doing... as everything. The C++ std is ridiculously paternalistic and protective and at the time insanely difficult to use correctly with things like floats.

Comment: @curiousguy It's not about knowing what you're doing. It's about making mistakes and the compiler not catching them because you hijacked the type safety system.

Comment: Since your wrapping `SDL` anyways, how about

Comment: @NikosC. Implicit conversions are an essential part of the language, not "hijacking".

Comment: @curiousguy I can't use the comment section to offer you a full explanation of why you're wrong, so I'll just point you to my comment about researching this yourself to find out why you don't want an implicit conversion here.

Comment: @NikosC. I am not "wrong" anymore than you are "wrong". These are difference on opinions or philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get those errors even in the absence of a `shared_ptr`, with a raw pointer, so I'll forego it for a moment.

The implicit conversion is applicable only from a `texture_t` *object*, not from a pointer to one (smart or otherwise). It doesn't work because neither a `shared_ptr` nor a dumb pointer has this conversion to an unrelated pointer type.

So to call any `SDL_func` and have the conversion kick in, you need to provide a glvalue (a reference) to a `texture_t`. It's easily accomplished with a de-reference.

```
SDL_func(*ptr, /* other args */); // ptr can be a dumb pointer too.
```

But having said all that, this feels like a leaky abstraction. If you made the effort to wrap `SDL_Texture*`, then don't stop at a half measure. Have `texture_t` be a fully value semantic type that provides abstracted *operations* over the SDL library. Don't burden calling code with knowing what library you use. It will make it all the more easier to switch libraries later should it be needed.

Answer (score 0):

C++ implicit conversion gives power to the coder. With a single conversion operator, one can enlarge so much the interface of a class. This what you want to do and I think it is a good idea.

But you should know that implicit conversions lead to a fast rise in code complexity. Beauty arise from complexity, but chaos is never far. So, we must learn to master the beast! So let's practice.

Conversions implemented by conversion operators are called user defined conversion. In the process of converting the argument to the function parameter, only one user defined conversion can take place. So even if `shared_ptr` had a conversion operator to the pointer it hold, you would still get the error.

So you must declare a conversion operator from `shared_ptr<texture_t>`, but that is impossible because conversion operators must be member functions. So one option could be to derive from `shared_ptr`:

```
class texture_ptr_t
  :public std::shared_ptr<texture_t> {

  operator SDL_texture*() const{
    return *get();
    }
  };
```

Now you have to carefully design this class, this one is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<texture_t>` through derived to base conversion... Maybe it is not an issue or maybe it will cause problem later.